# cannot find vendor package in windows

Tags: windows, go, godeps

I have my GOPATH and GOROOT set, currently trying to use a package located in the vendor folder, while doing go run in my windows I get

```
C:\resume>go run docs/generator.go
docs\generator.go:13:2: cannot find package "github.com/tidwall/gjson" in any 
of:
    C:\Go\src\github.com\tidwall\gjson (from $GOROOT)
    C:\resume\src\github.com\tidwall\gjson (from $GOPATH)
```

My GOROOT=C:\Go, GOPATH=C:\resume and PATH=C:\Go\bin

Comment: Whoever told you to set GOROOT is wrong: Don't. Are you sure you have gjson installed? If yes: Where? Are you sure `go run some/deep/path.go` is a good idea. You should provide _much_ more information.

Comment: If that is the extent of your PATH, you're going to have trouble finding anything other than the `go` tools. You also need `GOPATH/bin`, and probably whatever else was in your PATH before.